# can't send email to a mailgun's list with the API

Tags: php, email, mailgun, php-curl

I'm working on my own class that uses php to deliver all mailgun's operations through the API.

### 1st scenario

I use my class to create a list + add 2 members with real emails. My control panel shows these items created. When I send my message I inspect my logs from php + curl and I can see success but the message never reaches the list members!

### 2nd scenario

On the other hand when a list member sends a mail to list then all list members receive it as I was expected cause I made the list open to members.

### On the 1st scenario

I inspect the logs at Mailgun's panel and I can see accepted.

I suspected sth might be wrong in my domain record settings but Mailgun has verified my domain from godaddy.

Another possibility might be that my account is flex and I should add a debit card that's why they deny to deliver my message.

Anyway I tested in both the sandbox domain and a real one.

My DNS records at godaddy implement the following:

```
MX for domain.com because I forward mails to gmail
MX for mail.domain.com to make mailgun accept messages to my list
CNAME for both domains as proposed
A for both domains
TXT for both domains as proposed
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

### How I send the message

I implemented a method that sends a request at API endpoint `https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/DOMAIN/messages` where `DOMAIN` is replaced from the sandbox or real domain.

I use this method for

- 1 recipient --> **passes**
- a batch of recipients --> **passes**
- a mail list --> ***fails***

The [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html) says nothing for different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange API indeed!

### Mailing lists guidelines:

1. your list has access level `readonly` then you don't have to add this list in your recipients
2. your list has access level `members` then **ADD** the list to the recipients
3. your list has access level `everyone` then you don't have to add this list in your recipients.

Now, send an authenticated message with the API - this is called `administrator` at the docs(?)

Case (2) seems logical as any address which is not a member can't - and shouldn't - send a message to the list **even the API itself**!

But wait, this is **NOT** the end of the story for case (2): when you send the message to the list you should define `from` value **that same list** otherwise your message is accepted but never delivered!

Hopefully my code handles all the above cases automatically although I had to make a `sendToList` method that calls eventually the generic `send()`!